# User-defined exception

Tags: java, exception

I have some issues with this code. I get this error:: Check if exception is thrown correctly in getCandidateDetails method. Though test cases are passing 85%.

Candidate.java

```java
public class Candidate {
    
    private String name;
    private String gender;
    private double expectedSalary;
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public double getExpectedSalary() {
        return expectedSalary;
    }
    public void setExpectedSalary(double expectedSalary) {
        this.expectedSalary = expectedSalary;
    }
}
```

Main.java

```java
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        /* code */
        
    }
       public static Candidate getCandidateDetails() throws InvalidSalaryException{
           try{
           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
           String name = sc.nextLine();
           String gender = sc.nextLine();
           double expectedSalary = sc.nextDouble();
           if(expectedSalary < 10000){
               throw new InvalidSalaryException("Registration Failed. Salary cannot be less than 10000.");
           }
           Candidate c = new Candidate();
           return c;
           
           }catch(InvalidSalaryException ex){
               return null;
           }
           
       }
}
```

InvalidSalaryException.java

```
public class InvalidSalaryException extends Exception{
    public InvalidSalaryException(String str){
        super(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `getCandidateDetails()` doesn't throw `InvalidSalaryException`. It *catches* `InvalidSalaryException` and returns null. If it's supposed to *throw* `InvalidSalaryException`, then remove the `try`/`catch` inside that method.

Comment: Thanks, Got it. I am new to java, that's why I am having these type of problem.

Comment: In ``getCandidateDetails()`` You get the details from the user, but you create a Candidate without these details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about your problem but:

> Having some issues with this code.I am getting this error:: Check if
> exception is thrown correctly in getCandidateDetails method. **Though
> test cases are passing 85%.**

If your code does that (I indented it):

```
public static Candidate getCandidateDetails() throws InvalidSalaryException { // (1)
  try{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = sc.nextLine();
    String gender = sc.nextLine();
    double expectedSalary = sc.nextDouble();
    if(expectedSalary < 10000){
      throw new InvalidSalaryException("Registration Failed. Salary cannot be less than 10000."); // (2)
    }
    Candidate c = new Candidate();
    return c;
  } catch (InvalidSalaryException ex) { // (3)
    return null;
  }
}
```

Then

1. You are telling Java that the method might throw an `InvalidSalaryException`
2. You are throwing said exception.
3. You are catching the exception before returning `null`.

You should *not* catch the exception and let it go to the parent callers.

Besides, if you are unit testing this method, you are in serious trouble if you use `System.in`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test if the method `getCandidateDetails()` creates a valid object/record or throws an exception Don't catch the exception internally.

Since `Java 15` you can use a `record` for stroring data instead of a class in order to reduce boilerplate code.
https://dzone.com/articles/a-first-look-at-records-in-java-14

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
   public static void main (String[] args) {

        try {

            Candidate c = getCandidateDetails();
            System.out.println(c.toString());
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }           

    }

   public static Candidate getCandidateDetails() throws InvalidSalaryException{
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       String name = sc.nextLine();
       String gender = sc.nextLine();
       double expectedSalary = sc.nextDouble();
       if(expectedSalary < 10000){
           throw new InvalidSalaryException("Registration Failed. Salary cannot be less than 10000.");
       }
       return new Candidate(name,gender,expectedSalary);    
   }
}


record Candidate(String name, String gender, double salary){}

class InvalidSalaryException extends IllegalArgumentException{
    public InvalidSalaryException(String str){
        super(str);
    }
}
```